# how to get data order by time even through the data order is chaotic in firebase database?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

There are lot of messages in my firebase database, each message has a child called `time`, `time` is million seconds generated by `new Date()`. However these messages are not stored in the database in the order of this value. Some messages which has larger value of `time` are stored early than some messages which has smaller value of `time`. The order is chaotic.

I want to get all messages which `time` is between `start` to `end` and sort these messages in a correct order according to the value of time, this is my code:

```
ref.orderByChild("time").startAt(start).endAt(end).once("value").then(...)
```

But it doesn't work, the messages cannot be sorted.

Can you help how to implement it?

Comment: The code you show doesn't actually do anything with the data yet. Can yoou show how you handle the data, as it may well be that you've made a mistake in there?

Comment: Things that would help troubleshoot this: 1) see the exact values of `start` and `end` that you're passing in. You can do this by logging those values in your code, and then including the updated code and its output in your question, 2) see the code of how you handle the results of your query. Here too it's easiest if you log results, and include that output in your question too, 3) see the JSON at `ref` that you're querying (as text, no screenshots please).

Comment: Thanks Frank, it deed depends how to handling the data. I use sort(a,b) to order the results, it works now.

Comment: Hey lei lei. You shouldn't have to re-order the data client side. But we can't say why that is needed without seeing how you handle the query results in your code.